# App Icon not Shown in Title Bar in UWP für WinUI 3 / Uno

Tags: uwp, titlebar, winui-3, appbar, uno

I'm developing an UWP App with UNO / WinUI 3.
I have put images into the Images folder in the UWP project and the application icon is shown in the taskbar as well as application icon at the exe-file.

But unfortunately the App Icon is not shown in Window App Bar although I set the application icon for the UWP app.

Also the title in the app bar is always 'WinUI Desktop' although I set the Display Name in the App Manifest.

[image: Window App Bar]

Please tell me, how can I bringt the app icon to be shown in the app bar and set the window title.

Comment: UWP is not the same as WinUI3. So is it a UWP app or a WinUI3 app?

Comment: I use WinUI3 with UNO. The projet where I've the problem is the one for Windows Apps.

Comment: You need to use win32 api to change the Icon. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Recent add in github link pointed to by Roy Li, In your main window's _Loaded event.

```
this.AppWindow.SetIcon("Assets/MyCustomIcon.ico");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no icon property or method from the [Window Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.window?view=windows-app-sdk-1.2). The solution is to use the Win32 APIs - [WM_SETICON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-seticon) using PInvoke.

You might need to refer to @marb2000's reply from github link: [How to change the Window Icon in WinUI Desktop](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/4056)